# Grab data from multiple tables using Left Outer Join - PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, inner-join, outer-join

I'm trying to connect to 3 tables using LEFT OUTER JOIN. I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly.

**Tables are:** rates, countries and service_types

Query:

```
$sql = "SELECT rates.rate_id, rates.initial_change, service_types.service, countries.country 
FROM rates 
LEFT OUTER JOIN service_types ON rates.service_id = service_types.serviceType_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN countries ON rates.from_id = country.country_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN countries ON rates.to_id = country.country_id 
ORDER BY service_types.serviceType_id ASC";
$statement = $con_db->exec($sql);
$result = $statement->fetchAll();//error points to this line
```

This is the error message:

**Fatal error**:  Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in

Comment: The line the error points to, probably isn't the problem - I think it's throwing an error because $result is null due to $con_db->exec($sql); not returning anything. Why are you using exec(), not query()? Assuming that you're using a mysqli object to connect to your database.

Comment: @JonStory Thanks. I'm using pdo

Comment: Ah of course, I didn't pick up on the slight clue when you put "PDO" in capital letters in the title of the question :p - I'd still try with a simpler query (one which you know is returning a result). If that works, it's just that your query isn't returning anything - why are you using Left Outer Joins, what are you actually trying to do with this query?

Comment: @JonStory I'm referring `countries` and `service_types` TABLEs to get the country name and service name by joining their IDs with the ID on `rates` table. And then pass them along with the other data on `rates` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I noticed is the way your accessing your tables is incorrect. I'm guessing the SQL is invalid, which is returning null from `exec`. Try changing your query to this:

```
$sql = "SELECT rates.rate_id, rates.initial_change, service_types.service, countries1.country, countries2.country 
FROM rates 
LEFT OUTER JOIN service_types ON rates.service_id = service_types.serviceType_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN countries as countries1 ON rates.from_id = countries1.country_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN countries as countries2 ON rates.to_id = countries2.country_id 
ORDER BY service_types.serviceType_id ASC";
```

Note the country changed to countries1 & countries2 in the join condition, and also the columns in the select.

Comment: Woops, I made a mistake. See the updated version with the aliases. Basically, if your joining to the same table twice, you have to alias the tables because otherwise by just referring to `countries`, you won't know which one you're referring to.